# Difference between how to create C# objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, arraylist

I'm a C# developer and I'm learning Javascript.

> I noticed on C# the way to create an object is like this:

```
public class Member
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Sex { get; set; }

    public Member (string _name, int _age, string _sex)
    {
        Name = _name;
        Age = _age;
        Sex = _sex;
    }
}
```

> On javascript, I found just only one way to do it. Is so much
>   different, I didn't find another way:

```
var Member = {Name:"John", Age:65, Sex:"Male"};
```

So, the next doubt is I need to use it on a table. So I need an array of these objects 'Member'.

Normally, what would I do?

> C#

```
public ObservableCollection<Member> MyMembers = new ObservableCollection<Member>(){
new Member("Ryan",18,"Male"),
new Member("Gabriel",51,"Male"),
new Member("Samantha",14,"Female")
};
```

> on Javascript?

```
var Member1 = {Name:"Ryan", Age:18, Sex:"Male"}; 
var Member2 = {Name:"Gabriel", Age:51, Sex:"Male"}; 
var Member3 = {Name:"Samantha", Age:14, Sex:"Female"}; 
var MyMembers = [Member1, Member2, Member3];
```

or

```
var MyMembers = new Array(Member1, Member2, Member3);
```

I'm on the right way, or I have some better option to do it?
Remembering I will show it on a table. On C# ObservableCollection is the best choice.

Comment: I'd recommend using Code Review rather than Stack Overflow for queries like this.

Comment: This is too broad! You should go around the net and learn more about JS, there're tons of tutorials...

Comment: There are a myriad of ways to create JS objects. The one you found is called "object literals". Look around a bit more.

Comment: You could have said to me the other names of the another methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create something similar to class in JS too.

```
var Member = function(name,age,sex){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
}
```

And then initialize an instance like this:

```
var m = new Member('Ryan',21,'male')
```

For more information you should look in a tutorial of JS OOP. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) is a good source, but if it doesn't fit your needs, just google for another one.

Comment: Thanks man, this will help me. I already saw it, but this went unnoticed.
I found on the upper answer:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you should be able to do it the same way you did it in C#. Just instantiate the objects in the array.

```
var MyMembers = [{stuff}, {stuff}, {stuff}];
```

Additionally, it IS possible to define actual named objects with constructors in javascript. Take a look at the w3 page for that.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp

Comment: You help me a lot too, I can proceed now with my study!